# Oracle APEX 20.2 - handling opening app in new TAB

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to handle opening app in new tab in the same browser.
When I am logged in to one tab and will open a new tab and log in again, then return to the first tab and click wherever the error page appears with information about the ended session.
How can I handle it so that when opening the application in a new tab, there is a message that app is already open and that you cannot log in again and the session does not end in the first tab. Another solution is to prevent the error page from appearing in the first tab, but to open the login page.

Answer (score 1):

This is an an annoying facet to APEX session management that usually boils down to becoming a training issue. There are a few options to explore.

If the users are opening the URL from a standard link, then you could enable [re-join session](http://deneskubicek.blogspot.com/2014/06/apex-50-rejoin-session.html) for that home page.

You could suggest users open a new tab from a link within the application.

Both options will result in two tabs using the same session, which can cause issues with shared session state, but the new tab link could be defined to [clone the session](https://tedstruik-oracle.nl/ords/f?p=25384:1136::::::).

Either way, when one of these tabs times out, then the other tabs using that session will have also timed out, and the only pleasant way forward is to close all but one tab.

You might also consider enabling some form of single-sign on.